# How do I protect myself when using a public network?

Tags: vpn, dns, router

I'm in a hostel with plenty of software engineers. I want to make sure I have some protection.

I quickly read about dnscrypt and some VPN solutions.

What measures can I take to ensure my data traffic remains protected?

PS: This is really not the same question as [VPN Authentication over WiFi -- Is it secure?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/46379/vpn-authentication-over-wifi-is-it-secure). That question would be a follow up question to this one.

Comment: Perhaps a more appropriate dup target: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37597/how-to-use-public-wifi-safely

Answer (score 3):

Here are some useful tips from Kaspersky Lab’s team of Internet security experts:

**Be aware**
    Public Wi-Fi is inherently insecure – so be cautious.

**Remember – any device could be at risk**
    Laptops, smartphones, and tablets are all susceptible to the wireless security risks.

**Treat all Wi-Fi links with suspicion**
    Don’t just assume that the Wi-Fi link is legitimate. It could be a bogus link that has been set up by a cybercriminal that’s trying to capture valuable, personal information from unsuspecting users. Question everything – and don’t connect to an unknown or unrecognized wireless access point.

**Try to verify it’s a legitimate wireless connection**
    Some bogus links – that have been set up by malicious users – will have a connection name that’s deliberately similar to the coffee shop, hotel, or venue that’s offering free Wi-Fi. If you can speak with an employee at the location that’s providing the public Wi-Fi connection, ask for information about their legitimate Wi-Fi access point – such as the connection’s name and IP address.

**Use a VPN (virtual private network)**
    By using a VPN when you connect to a public Wi-Fi network, you’ll effectively be using a ‘private tunnel’ that encrypts all of your data that passes through the network. This can help to prevent cybercriminals – that are lurking on the network – from intercepting your data.

**Avoid using specific types of website**
    It’s a good idea to avoid logging into websites where there’s a chance that cybercriminals could capture your identity, passwords, or personal information – such as social networking sites, online banking services, or any websites that store your credit card information.

**Consider using your cell phone**
    If you need to access any websites that store or require the input of any sensitive information – including social networking, online shopping, and online banking sites – it may be worthwhile accessing them via your cell phone network, instead of the public Wi-Fi connection.

**Protect your device against cyberattacks**
    Make sure all of your devices are protected by a rigorous anti-malware and security solution – and ensure that it’s updated as regularly as possible.

[Source](https://usa.kaspersky.com/internet-security-center/internet-safety/public-wifi)